# Test.QuickCheck not generating random values correctly

Tags: haskell

I am using Test.QuickCheck to generate random Sudoku puzzles.

```
data Sudoku = Sudoku { getSudoku :: [[Maybe Int]] } deriving (Show, Eq)

rows :: Sudoku -> [[Maybe Int]]
rows (Sudoku rs) = rs

--B1
printSudoku :: Sudoku -> IO ()
printSudoku s = do
    putStrLn . unlines . map (map (maybe '.' (head . show))) $ rows s

--C1
cell :: Gen (Maybe Int)
cell = suchThatMaybe (frequency [(90, choose (0,0)),(10, choose(1,9))]) (/=0)

--C2
instance Arbitrary Sudoku where
    arbitrary = do
        rows <- sequence [ sequence [ cell | j <- [1..9] ] | i <- [1..9] ]
        return (Sudoku rows)

--C3
prop_Sudoku :: Sudoku -> Bool
prop_Sudoku = isSudoku

checkRandomSudoku :: IO [Bool]
checkRandomSudoku = do
    s <- sample' (arbitrary :: Gen Sudoku)
    return $ map isSudoku s
```

The code runs fine. However, when I perform

a <- sample' (arbitrary :: Gen Sudoku)

sequence $ map printSudoku a

it returns something like this :

```
....5..3.
...4.....
...2.....
...5.....
.........
...33....
...5.....
...2.4...
.........

.........
.343.....
.........
......9.2
.........
45....5.1
.2......7
.7..88.34
.9....6..

....2..8.
.2121638.
.7.7...9.
4..45.6..
.....6.2.
..6.6....
53..9.6..
..9....7.
.47892...

.373411..
5...3282.
...45..9.
8989..18.
31.8113..
9..35.6..
4.685....
.4....39.
7..6.5.76

48.178.53
1.871.4.4
3165.17..
.1...7.59
.98126.51
6.6...775
9.4636952
.5..239..
372.....8

.34.73129
.5.8.27.1
344.34931
28.6.94.1
6327.3..8
3743.5496
93...7984
..82.8...
..3.54.93

273847853
5568.7465
832.73515
3766..6.7
.7.196256
1.96.9.3.
.7156.268
1615.196.
.392..633

731652284
863.8.768
31..5.5.6
961.5.467
1245.1159
5..275471
52.727759
6.656.849
99.72352.
```

which obviously is not random at all. The distribution of empty cells is very high initially and then slowly decreases. Am I using the wrong function or in the wrong way? Thanks

Comment: As a comment on your approach (rather than your description of the current problem): I suspect this isn't a great idea. Generating correct sudoku puzzles seems like one of those things that sound easy but isn't, and I bet you're going to run into a dozen weird problems once you solve this one. But there's lots of puzzles already out there in the wild -- can you skip all the problems by just using an existing corpus?

Comment: I'm just following the exercise found [here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2013/course/TDA555/lab3.html). I kinda agree with you. In my example, you could see that it is not even checking if there are repeated numbers in a row/column/box, but I would still like to understand why the it didn't generate the random numbers as I would expect it to. Especially frequency, I would have expected more unfilled entries since I have it much more weight than numbered entries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is that QuickCheck tries progressively bigger test cases. This is described in the [resizing](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual_body.html#15) section of the manual.

In the case of `suchThatMaybe` increasing the size makes it retry generating an arbitrary to match the predicate you passed to it. You can see that in the source http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#suchThatMaybe. The interesting code is:

```
try _ 0 = return Nothing
try k n = do x <- resize (2*k+n) gen
             if p x then return (Just x) else try (k+1) (n-1)
```

What's happening is that `suchThatMaybe` retries `n` times where `n` depends on the size parameter passed to the generator.

[`sample'` tries the sizes `[0,2..20]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#sample%27) which get propagated all the way to `suchThatMaybe`.

You can override the increasing sizes by calling `resize` on a generator:

```
>>> a <- sample' $ (resize 2 arbitrary :: Gen Sudoku)
>>> sequence $ map printSudoku a
.....8.5.
.......4.
.........
4..25...5
......9..
....5....
........7
.....7...
...4.....

...5.....
.......4.
...6...6.
..14.....
...7...7.
....2....
.....6...
...4..572
.4.....6.

..6..8...
..4......
.........
......9..
839......
67..4....
.5.......
....5....
........3

4...1....
7..9.39..
....6....
...4.1...
.........
.........
..9....6.
.2.9...84
.....8...

.64......
..3.44...
4.......4
....1..8.
.9.......
34.......
.....6...
18.2..593
.4.7.....

.........
...8..6..
.2......5
...5.....
.2.......
........6
.3....13.
8.1.2..85
....5....

..7......
..67...5.
..6......
27....1.9
.9.......
78.....7.
......34.
.......2.
..81...81

3.1......
.........
.....6...
.........
.16.71...
.........
.2.......
.........
.....9.1.

..65..6.9
........5
..1.4....
....86...
.2..2..2.
.....9...
..6......
.........
...7..855

.......94
...14..8.
.....4...
...3....9
.........
.....5...
.5.......
45.....8.
..48.....

4........
......3..
5......4.
.4..6..2.
..3......
.........
..9......
6..9.....
....7....
```

Comment: I see. I think it's rather unintuitive because the description for the function on hackage doesn't suggest it affects probability on its predicate. I'm curious to understand what suchThatMaybe could be used for without using resize though? If you would be so kind could you spare me an example? Thanks

Comment: The idea of `suchThatMaybe` is to cover as many different test cases as possible. So if you have a predicate that is very rarely satisfied it would be more likely to hit a positive test case by retrying.